# ¿Cómo cambiar una letra por otra en una cadena con una función recursiva en python?

Tags: python, funciones, recursión

Tengo un trabajo y no se como hacerlo ,lo que me piden es: 
Teniendo una secuencia de ADN hallarla cadena complementaria de esta a partir de unas equivalencias ( osea sustituir una letra por otra ).
Usando una función recursiva, sin usar el método replace.

| ADN | ARN |
| --- | --- |
| A | T |
| C | G |
| G | C |
| T | A |

Como resultado debería obtener:

La cadena de ADN es: AAAACCCGGT

Su cadena complementaria es: TTTTGGGCCA

Lo que he intentado hacer es esto, pero no funciona:

```
 def complementaria_ADN_recursiva(adn):
     if "A" in adn:
     return "T"
 elif "C" in adn:
    return "G"
 elif "G" in adn:
    return "C"
 else:
    return"A"

adn = "AAAACCCGGT"
complementaria = complementaria_ADN_recursiva(adn)

print(f"La cadena de ADN es : {adn}")
print(f"La cadena complementaria es: {complementaria}")
```

Comment: Debe ser obligatoriamente una función recursiva?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Comment: Sí , debe ser una función recursiva

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución a tu problema!. Lo único que cambié fue la función `complementaria_ADN_recursiva`.

El error sucedía ya que la función `in` no funciona para detectar la letra de una palabra, lo que podíamos hacer era reemplazar esta función por un `if`. Siguiendo la tabla que dejaste **el codigo quedaría así:**

```
def complementaria_ADN_recursiva(adn):
    #Aqui creamos una variable para luego ir sumando las letras
    ADNcomplementaria = ""
    
    #Creamos un bucle para que por cada A se reemplaze a T
    for letra in adn:
        if letra == "A":
            #Sumamos las letras
            ADNcomplementaria = ADNcomplementaria + "T"
            

        elif letra == "C":
            ADNcomplementaria = ADNcomplementaria + "G"

        elif letra == "G":
            ADNcomplementaria = ADNcomplementaria + "C"

       

        else:
            ADNcomplementaria = ADNcomplementaria + "A"

    #regresamos la variable ADNcomplementaria
    return ADNcomplementaria



adn = "AAAACCCGGT"
complementaria = complementaria_ADN_recursiva(adn)

print(f"La cadena de ADN es : {adn}")
print(f"La cadena complementaria es: {complementaria}")
```

Ahí te deje algunos **comentarios** para que entiendas de una mejor manera **la respuesta**. Si te fue de ayuda no olvide de darle cheque y flecha arriba a mi respuesta, un gustazo ayudarte Lidius